# Clean up processes started during by test case execution

Tags: subprocess, pytest

I'm building an application which starts processes using `subprocess.Popen()`. Those processes may, depending on what they do, start processes of their own. As part of by test suite, I want to thoroughly test that functionality, but I fear that eventual bugs in my code may lead to numerous processes (across the many test cases) staying alive, which I would have to clean up manually.

Is there some functionality in *py.test*, or a plugin, which could solve this problem and clean up all processes started during the execution of a test case? Bonus points if processes, which had to be cleaned up, are reported and/or counted towards a test case failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yield_fixture](https://pytest.org/latest/yieldfixture.html) decorator to define *setup* & *teardown* parts of creating processes, stores it's PID's and then kill them all. Ex:

```python
import pytest
import subporcess

@pytest.yield_fixture
def run_sh():
    sh = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    yield sh
    sh.kill()

def test_popen(run_sh):
    assert run_sh.pid > 1
```

Comment: This will only terminate the process started by the fixture but not any subprocesses.

Comment: That seems like a plan! I will just have to write a fixture which will provide the process spawning capability to my test case so that it can inject the group-changing behavior.